# Error while running a while loop in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, aix

I am executing a script and getting error in the following code. It is working fine on RedHat but in AIX7.1 it is giving errors :

```
while read line
do
read -A arr <<< $line
ct="$(perl -e 'print time()')"
x=${arr[6]}
y="$(((ct-x)/60/60))"
if [ $y -gt 48 ];then
echo "${arr[0]} ${arr[3]} ${arr[5]} ${arr[6]}" >> $longrunning_jobs_tmp1
fi
done < $active_jobs_tmp4
```

I have correctly defined the variables also but still getting the following issue :

```
Job_Monitoring_Test.ksh[121]: 0403-057 Syntax error at line 123 : `<' is not expected.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running the script with `ksh88` on AIX while it was written for `ksh93`.

Try setting its shebang to:

```
#!/bin/ksh93
...
```

If `ksh93` is not available, perhaps `dtksh` would work. Otherwise, you need to port the script to `bash`.

Edit:

If the issue is with the `<<<` syntax, you can replace

```
read -A arr <<< $line
```

by:

```
read -A arr <<%EOF%
$line
%EOF%
```

Comment: I did this : which ksh93 and updated the script with following : #!/usr/bin/ksh93 , and again ran the script but again got same error

Comment: I guess AIX `ksh93` release is too old to support the `<<<` syntax. Have a look to its version with this command `ksh93 -c 'echo ${.sh.version}'` and compare with the one you get under Linux.

Comment: AIX is as follows : AIX 7.1- Version M 93t+ 2009-05-01  .My RedHat is as follows : Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01

Comment: Then it should support `<<<` which appeared with `ksh93m+`. What is line 123 ? Double check the script is run with ksh93.

Comment: Line 123 is following :     read -A arr <<< $line .                                        Also In the below code do i need to include $line in a new line :                                                                          read -A arr <<%EOF%
$line
%EOF%

Comment: Yes, just like I wrote it in my updated answer. Add `echo ksh_version=${.sh.version}` to the script to check it runs under the expected shell.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have/can you install Bash on your system?
Using the shebang `#/bin/bash` might solve a lot problems.
You still have to look at the options used in different commands like `find` (mtime), `date` and `sed` (-i option for inplace editing), but Bash specific constructions will work.